# Dereferencing vs Indexing on const string reference

Tags: c++, pointers

For const `string` reference variable `str` in the following piece of code:

Works well: `for(int i=0; str[i]; i++)`

Throws error: `for(int i=0; *(str+i); i++)`

> Error: error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const string {aka const std::basic_string}' and 'int')

```
// Return true if str is binary, else false
bool isBinary(const string &str)
{
   for(int i=0; *(str+i); i++){
       if(str[i]!='0' && str[i]!='1')
           return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

P.S.: I can understand this might be a naive question, but then I would be happy to be redirected to useful sources too!

Comment: `std::string` isn't the same as `char*`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I get where I am wrong, thanks for the help

Comment: To get the char pointer call string::c_str()

Comment: @FedeWar Didn't know this too; I'll be trying this

Comment: Try [the book guide and list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). (Found at the [C++ info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` is of type `std::string`, it is not `char*`, and there is no `operator+(int)` defined for it, what you can do is to get its size with `length` member function:

```
bool isBinary(const string &str)
{
   for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
       if(str[i]!='0' && str[i]!='1')
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

On the other hand, if you got a c string, you can do the second form, since c strings are just null terminated char arrays.

```
bool isBinary(const char *str)
{
   for(int i=0; *(str+i); i++){
       if(str[i]!='0' && str[i]!='1')
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, you could get c string from c++'s `std::string` with its `c_str()` member function.

```
const char *s = str.c_str();
```

Comment: Got it! Indeed, too naive to ask, thanks!

Comment: You could also mention, that you can get underlying `const char*` from `std::string` using [`std::string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: @Zereges Updated, thanks.